# Cakephp form input with datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I have used cakephp form input control to generate input field for the date/datetime and it generates several dropdowns to select month, year day etc.  and it works fine.

But my requirement was, i need to add jquery datepicker to the form element. I have done that by writing jQuery function in the head and it works fine. But everytime when i want to do this, i need to add the javascript stuff and need to manually specify the form control parameters.

Rather than doing like this i would like to know, whether can i overwrite the default form input control for the date fields with datepicker within elements? I dont want to do any modifications in the cakephp core, I would like to create this as a seperate element so that i can override and use.

Is it possible to do? if so can someone let me know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

**Additional Info:**
I still want to use the following code to generate the datepicker field automatically.

```
echo $this->Form->input('date_of_birth');
```

When I type this code, it should automatically create the textbox with datepicker. That's what I'm looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's you want is a [Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1097/Creating-Helpers).

The goal of a helper is to add more behavior in your template.

1. you define one
2. your call it in your template

for example I made one to have multicheckboxes in cakephp 1.2

```
class PcformHelper extends FormHelper {
    public function multiCheckboxes($modelName, $colName, $value, $values=array(),$title)   {
    }
}
```

then in the template I could do

```
echo $pcform->multiCheckboxes("Tips","groups",$group['Group']['g_id'], $p_groups,h($group['Group']['g_title']);
```

hope this could help

Comment: i said this worked wuth cake 1.2 if since then we have to use $this instead ok but a downvote for that... next time i will avoid to show the way to reach the goal with an example. its not very encouraging.regards

Comment: Hi, I understand your answer, but what i really need is i still want to do with the same calls as like the normal cakephp controls. Please check the question amendments for more details.

Comment: it was not me who downvoted. your idea is basically the right way. @sutha - follow the advice to extend the core form helper and overwrite the methods. this way you can attach your js datepicker with the same access from the outside (by using aliasing).

Comment: Thanks guys If that's the way I'll use it. I'm not much expert in writing helper elements. I'll choose it as the write answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

See generic solution (any CakePHP version) with jQuery-UI datapicker,

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/HTF5ExtFIes